# Find top n average values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
UID DATE GROUP VALUE
```

The data types are:

```
 VARCHAR DATE VARCHAR NUMERIC
```

Example:

```
abc1000 2012-09-01 1205 1000.0000
abc1000 2012-09-01 1210 1010.0000
abc1000 2012-09-02 1205 1100.0000
abc1000 2012-09-02 1210 1020.0000
def1010 2012-09-01 1205 2000.0000
```

I need to find the top N(15) values (VALUE) for each unique "UID+GROUP" and AVERAGE them so the output looks like this:

```
abc1000 1205 1050.0000
abc1000 1210 1015.0000
def1010 1205 2000.0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select uid, [group], avg(value)
from
(
 select *,
        row_number() over (partition by uid, [group] order by value desc) rn 
        from yourtable
) v
where rn<=15
group by uid, [group]
```

Comment: I think this is it! Please allow me to express my thanks... I spent 8 hours on this yesterday with no result and I am so grateful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You need to use `AVG` function

```
SELECT TOP 15 [UID], [GROUP], AVG(VALUE) avgValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY [UID], [GROUP]
ORDER BY avgValue DESC
```

or by using `CTE`

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [UID], [GROUP], AVG(VALUE) avgValue,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By AVG(VALUE) ORDER BY AVG(VALUE) DESC) as Row_Num
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY [UID], [GROUP]
)
SELECT [UID], [GROUP], avgValue
FROM cte 
WHERE Row_Num <= 15
```

this will allow the same total average of records to be on the top 15 list, example

```
1 , rec 1, 100
2 , rec 2, 98
....
....
....
14, recX , 76
15, recY , 76
16, recZ , 76
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe the other answer is what I'm looking for.